# apkPermissionsRequirePrivacyPolicy error on fastlane

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

Fastlane shows this error  when uploading apk to play store.

```
[!] Google Api Error: apkPermissionsRequirePrivacyPolicy: The apk has permissions that require a privacy policy set for the app, e.g: android.permission.CAMERA
```

If I did manual upload for APK, it could be uploaded.

However I already write these in manifest.

Where should I check adding to this?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRIGHT_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix it you need to set privacy policy URL in google play console.
Or remove the camera permission if you don't need it.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. please refer [this link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/07/29/simple-example-on-using-camera-access-permission-in-android-marshmallow/)

Comment: I know permission system has changed. however is it related with my problem? and how can I fix it??

Comment: I understood I need to set privacy policy link in store page in advance before using fastlane. I have thought I could do everything from fastlane though, I should check store page manually at the first time.